# Why is there an empty <a name="main"></a> in my templates?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

When I view source I see an empty  tag which appears just before the main template block. What's the reason for this. Is there any documentation on overriding outerLayoutBase.html ? (which is probably where this code is coming from)

Comment: It was more a question of why is ApostropheCMS adding crap into my templates

Answer (score 1):

Most likely used to create a bookmark or anchor, so when you do `page.html#main`, it will automatically jump to the beginning of the main template block.

https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/att_a_name.asp

This is deprecated in HTML5 though.